# How can I use polymorphic_path from Observer model's hook (rails4)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, observers, urlhelper

I can use `app.polymorphic_path(MyModel.first)` from console.
But nothing works like that:

```
class ModelsObserver < ActiveRecord::Observer
  observe :my_model, :my_model2
  def publish_data(rec) # rec is a model instance
     amqp_publish({
      # ...
      # show_path: Rails.application.helpers.polymorphic_path(rec)
      # show_path: ActionDispatch::Routing::PolymorphicRoutes.polymorphic_path(rec)
      show_path: application.polymorphic_path(rec)
    })
```

etc

Comment: can you elaborate a little more on what the problem is?

Comment: I get errors like that:

     *NoMethodError (undefined method polymorphic_path for #<Module:0x00000009d72ec8>):*

    *NoMethodError (undefined method polymorphic_path for #<MyRailsApplication::Application:0x0000000242b880>):*

etc

Comment: Now I use `"/#{rec.class.to_s.tableize}/#{rec.id}"` but this is a partial solution.